# На андроиде кнопка работает с айфона - нет

Tags: css3, html5

На андроиде кнопка прожимается, но когда заходишь с айфона, то она стоит на месте.

Как сделать чтобы эффект нажатия работал и на айфоне?

```css
.btn:link, .btn:visited {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  border: 0.2rem solid #F8E31A;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  color: #F8E31A;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 22rem;
  height: 6rem;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transition: all;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  animation-name: departure;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transition: all;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<a class="right-wraper__btn btn btn_main" href="#">связаться!</a>
```

Comment: - что семнадцать? 
- а что прибор?

Comment: Если вы заходите с браузера Safari ниже 9'ой версии, тогда в стили ещё нужно добавить `-webkit-transform: translateY(5px);`

Comment: А вообще, нужно добавить информацию о том, с какого вы браузера заходите на iPhone'е.

Comment: спасибо огромное за внимание! Но почему-то не помогло.... может есть ещё другой способ? вот ссылка на мой сайт на всякий случай. https://www.focik.online  Самое странное, что когда захожу с мака, то всё нормально работает, а как дело доходит до айфона, половина свойств не работает. Буду очень признателен любому ответу)) Но хотелось бы конечно решить проблему))